# Traefik with Docker-Compose not working as expected

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I am fairly new to using traefik, so I might be totally missing something simple, but I have the following docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: reverse_proxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: traefik:v2.0
    command:
    - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    - --entrypoints.web-secure.address=:443
    - --api.insecure=true
    - --providers.file.directory=/conf/
    - --providers.file.watch=true
    - --providers.docker=true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./scripts/certificates/conf/:/conf/
      - ./scripts/certificates/ssl/:/certs/
    networks:
      - bnkrl.io
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.bnkrl.io`)"
      - "traefik.docker.network=bnkrl.io"

  bankroll:
    container_name: bankroll
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: yarn start
    networks:
      - bnkrl.io


    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.bankroll.rule=Host(`bankroll.bnkrl.io`)"
      - "traefik.docker.network=bnkrl.io"
      - "traefik.http.services.bankroll.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.bankroll-https.rule=Host(`bankroll.bnkrl.io`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.bankroll-https.tls=true"

networks:
  bnkrl.io:
    external: true
```

But for some reason the following is happening:

Running curl when ssh'd into my bankroll container gives the following:

```
/usr/src/app# curl bankroll.bnkrl.io
curl: (7) Failed to connect to bankroll.bnkrl.io port 80: Connection refused
```

Despite having `- "traefik.http.services.bankroll.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"` label set up.

I am also unable to hit traefik from my application container:

```
curl traefik.bnkrl.io
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: traefik.bnkrl.io
```

Despite my expectation to be able to do so since they are both on the same network.

Any help with understanding what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated! My application (bankroll) is a very basic hello-world react app, but I don't think any of the details around that are relevant to the issue I'm facing.

EDIT: I am also not seeing any error logs on traefik side of things.

Comment: Even after removing the port 80 from my bankroll service (which I added when I was just throwing stuff on a wall to see if anything stuck) I am still seeing the same behavior.
EDIT: I've updated my question with my updated docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You are using host names that are not declared and therefore are unreachable.

To reach a container from another container, you need to use the service name, for example, if you connect to `bankroll` from the `reverse-proxy` it will hit the other service.

While if you want to access them from the host machine, you will have to publish the ports (which you did, it's all the stuff in `ports` in your Docker-compose file) and access from localhost or from your machine local IP address instead of `traefik.bnkrl.io`.

If you want to access from `traefik.bnkrl.io`, you will have to declare this host name, and point it to the place where the Docker containers are running from.

So either a DNS record in the domain `bnkrl.io` pointing to your local machine, or a [HOSTS file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) entry in your computer pointing to `127.0.0.1`.

Another note: For SSL you are going to need a valid certificate to use for the host name. While in local development, you can use the self-signed certificate provided by Traefik, but you may have to install it in the computer connecting to the service, or allow untrusted certificates from your browser, or wherever you are making the requests from (some browsers no longer support using self-signed certificates). For SSL on the Internet you will need to look at things like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed response. How come I am able to run the following:
`root@575c1ca72a72:/usr/src/app# curl bankroll.bnkrl.io:3000`
and get an appropriate response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ionic App</title>

    <base href="/" />
...
Sorry for terrible formatting, I thought comments would function similarly to posts

Comment: I guess my confusion is that I would suspect that running curl on bankroll.bnkrl.io from within the docker container would reach out to localhost:80, which is traefik, which would see the hostname I am trying to hit is 'bankroll.bnkrl.io' and forward it accordingly. So i'm not sure of two things:
1. Why is it not forwarding the request correctly using the loadbalancer I created in the traefik labels.
2. How come bankroll.bnkrl.io:3000 points to localhost:3000. I feel like it would be like localhost.bnkrl.io:3000 which would fail.